# positioning pseudo-element above div

Tags: html, css

I have a div with content in it and I want to put an element on top of it using :before.

CSS

```
 div:before {
       content: '';
       display: block;
       width: 30px;
       height: 2px;
  }
```

but I can't get it on top, only to the left of it.

EDIT (more clarification)

I am looking for a border on the top, but not one that goes all the way (100% of the div) so I want to add a pseudo element with a defined height and width

Comment: Can you add jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
div{
  width: 100px;
padding: 20px;
background: lavender;
position: relative;
}    
div:before {
   content: '';
   display: block;
   width: 30px;
   height: 2px;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
background: #000;
top:-2px;
  }
```

```html
<div>Test content</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vgnojc56/1/

Answer (score 1):

OP said in a comment:

> the problem is i want a top-border but I don't want the border to go 100% the width of the div

This solves with a `box-sizing` property and without `:before` pseudo class:

```
div {
    border-top: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

See it run: https://jsfiddle.net/8hs5n7sd/

## EDIT

After comments, you can make this:

```
div {
    position:relative;
    top: 20px;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background-color:black;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
div:before {
    content :" ";
    position :absolute;
    top: -5px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color:red;
    width: 90%;
    left: 5%;
}
```

See it run: https://jsfiddle.net/8hs5n7sd/1/

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to your answer. I am looking for a border on the top, but not one that goes all the way (100% of the div) so I want to add a pseudo element with a defined height and width

Comment: I understand you bad. Sorry. I understand that you need to add a border without increase the width (or height) or your div. With this it solves. But if you need a border a little bit small than the div you can make the edited answer said.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should increase `height` from `2px` to `more` to get the content in top.

```
div:before {
       content: 'hi';
       display: block;
       width: 30px;
       height: 15px;
       border-top: 1px solid red;
  }
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: the problem is i want a top-border but I don't want the border to go 100% the width of the div

Comment: If u declare width to 30px than why the border will go 100%. add border-top: 1px solid red. The border will be displayed only that much where you declare width value